# Can anyone explain me what is happening in 9th line "words.each do|word|"? why it is not words in the pipe why it's word?

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Text please: "
text = gets.chomp

puts "Redacted letter: "
redacted = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")

words.each do|word|
  if word == redacted
    print "REDACTED "
  else
    print word +" "
  end
end
```

Can anyone explain me what is happening in 9th line, `words.each do |word|`? why it is not words in the pipe why it's word?

And if i want to print out "REDACTED" as output what i have to do?
please need help.

Answer (score 2):

`words` is the whole list (of words found by splitting up the input text wherever there's a space) .  More technically, it's an instance of the class [`Array`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html), which has a method named [`each`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-each) designed to run some block of code repeatedly - once for every element of the array. In this case, that means once per word in the input text.

Your snippet is calling `each` on `words` and passing a block of code to it - that's the `do`...`end` construct. (Code blocks can also be delimited by curly braces, `{`...`}`.)

The first thing inside the code block after the keyword `do` is a list of parameter names inside pipes.  When the block is executed, any arguments passed to it will be given names from that list, in order.

Every time `Array#each` runs the block, it passes a single element of the array as an argument. In this case, that element will be assigned to a local variable named `word` within the body of the block.

So everything from `do` through `end` happens multiple times - once for every word in the array.  The first time, `word` holds the first word.  The second time, it holds the second word. And so on.

`words` never changes; it always holds the whole array.

You could, if you wanted, use the name `words` inside the block as well; it would be confusing, and the code in the block would not be able to access the outer `words`, but that outer `words` would still be intact at the end of the loop.

Sample run:

```
 Code>   puts "Text please: "
 Output> Text please: 

 Code>   text = gets.chomp
 Input>  Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party. 
 Result> text == "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party."

 Code>   puts "Redacted letter: "
 Output> Redacted letter:
 Code>   redacted = gets.chomp
 Input>  good
 Result>  redacted == "good"

 Code> words = text.split(" ")
 Result> words == [ "Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", 
                    "men", "to", "come", "to", "the", "aid", "of", "their",
                    "party." ]

 Code> words.each do |word|
 Result> word == "Now"    

 Code> if word == redacted
 Result> if "Now" == "good"  #=> false
 Code> else 
 Code> print word +" "
 Output> "Now "

 Code> words.each do |word|
 Result> word == "is"
 Code> if word == redacted
 Result> if "is" == "good"  #=> false
 Code> else 
 Code> print word +" "
 Output> "is "  (Cumulative output: "Now is ")
```

.... and so on for "the", "time", "for", "all" ...

```
 Code> words.each do |word|
 Result> word == "good"
 Code> if word == redacted
 Result> if "good" == "good"  #=> true
 Code>  print "REDACTED "
 Output> "REDACTED "
```

... and so on for men, to, come, to, the, aid, of, their, party.

```
 Code> end
 Cumulative Output> Now is the time for all REDACTED men to come to the aid of their party.
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions succinctly. You ask three questions...

1) "what is happening in 9th line": In the beginning, you have this array of `words`, to which you apply `.each`. What this does is allows you to iterate over **each** element in the array. Each element is given to the `word` variable in the lines of code you have right after that `do`, and before the last `end` in your code (what you have there between the `do` and the last `end` is called a "block" of code, by the way).

2) "why it is not words in the pipe why it's word?" Well, this is Ruby syntax, really - the two things are different. The array you are iterating over is called `words`, and you want to do something with each one of those words in that array. People tend to use a **plural** for the name of container, like an array, and a **singular** when talking about "each" item in the array. So, when you say `words.each`, you tend to think of each one as a single "word". You could have used any name to represent a single element in the array called `words`, but `word` seems best.

3) "if i want to print out "REDACTED" as output": a) Run the code. b) When it asks for `Text please:`, give it one word (say "ABC" without quotes). c) When it then asks `Redacted letter:`, give it the same word (again, "ABC" without quotes). You should then be greeted with `REDACTED`.

Now that your stated questions are answered, if you want to go into learning why this happens, consider the `if` statement. You are going through each element in the array `words`, and seeing as how there is only one `word` ("ABC") this will only happen once. Since that "word" is exactly the same as the string currently in the variable `redacted`, the comparison turns out to be equal ("ABC" == "ABC"), and the command `print "REDACTED "` is run once and only once. If you had more words in the array, and none of them were "ABC", you'd also see those in your output

I'm glad you are learning Ruby. It's a great language! Keep up with it. You'll get better over time, and it's very rewarding.